# How to pass a variable from the url thru to a submit?

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables, int

I am passing a variable `fprs` thru the URL and i can't seem to get it past the submit event. My Variable `$userID` which is from the URL becomes out of scope when I hit my submit button. How can I pass this variable to my query successfully?
As you can see, i am getting the fprs from the URL, transfering it to the `$userID`, then when I submit, the $userID becomes empty.

```
$userID ="";
$usID="";

if(isset($_GET['fprs'])){       
    $usID = substr($_GET['fprs'], 8);
}

$userID = intval($usID);

if(isset($_POST['btnChange'])){
    if($Validate == true){

        $link = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
        var_dump($userID);
        $updatePassStr= "Update User set Pass='$hashPass' WHERE UserID='$userID'";
        if($update = mysqli_query($link, $updatePassStr)){
            echo "good";
        }
        else{
            $Error = "Some error occured with the database, please wait a little and try again.";
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably need to add the fprs to your POST (form) action="my site.com/?fprs=VALUE&somethingelse=VALUE2"

Comment: Yes your right I left that out. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden field `userID`in your form and store `$userID` there. After submit, retrieve the value with `$userID=$_POST['userID']`.

Comment: Controlling GET and POST separately can hold a certain meaning in the choice of the page-design. I don't think the question pointed out to parse the data through POST.